# Error with automated report email

Tags: reporting, email

I've set up a report to be emailed to a high ranking (full license, view all) user in an organization on a weekly basis, which has worked for a few months now. Last week I added a new (full license) user to a role below him, and transferred a few accounts to this user. All of a sudden, the last two weeks instead of the report email, he's gotten an error message with the following message. Any ideas?

> Salesforce.com could not email the report to any of the specified
>   recipients. Check that recipients are specified and that they have the
>   appropriate permissions to view the report.

**UPDATE:** In this case, it appears the user who was receiving the emails due to being in a specified role had their role changed, leaving only inactive users in that role. However, the radio button "To me and/or others..." was chosen, so the running user should receive the report. Perhaps the fact that the others ends up being empty affects something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it appears the user who was receiving the emails due to being in a specified role had their role changed, leaving only inactive users in that role. Additionally, I misinterpreted the radio button "me and/or other users" to imply that I was getting the email regardless, rather than needing to physically put my user in the right select group.